# Owl Carousel.js and Bootstrap Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am using the Bootstrap Freelance theme (http://startbootstrap.com/templates/freelancer/) and would like to incorporate Own Carousel.js (http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/basic.html).

I would like to click on an image, and have this open in a modal window, then be able to scroll left/right between images.

All seems to be working apart from the images open VERY small initially, until I resize the window then boom - fine! Seems to be on initial loading of the modal window something is hapenning, however when I make any change to the window size, such as pressing F12 (for dev tools) the image then resizes and looks fine. Any suggestions? Is this likely to be a css or js issue?

My html

```
<!-- Portfolio Modals -->
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">


                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h2>Project Title</h2>
                        <hr class="star-primary">  

                        <div class="owl-carousel">
                        <div><img src="img/portfolio/cabin.png"> </div>
                        <div><img src="img/portfolio/cake.png"> </div>
                        <div><img src="img/portfolio/circus.png"> </div>
                        </div>               

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a conflict with another js file possibly?

I have included the following js files before the `</head>` tag - are they in the correct order?;

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

CSS files in order;

```
owl.carousel.css
owl.theme.default.css
bootstrap.min.css
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: That carousel is slick. On a side note, though, it would probably be beneficial to include CSS.

Comment: Thanks Aibrean - now updated with CSS and progress! Yea it's very slick - would be awesome to get it working for my portfolio website!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found the answer hopefully it helps someone else, it was an issue with the event - instead of `show.bs.modal` it has to be `shown.bs.modal` according to the Bootstrap docs.

Also, you need to include the auto refresh plugin available in the developers website.